# How to find the integral $\int (x^2-6x)^{-3/2}\,dx$?

Tags: integration

What is the integral of $(x^2-6x)^{-3/2}$ ?

[image]

Comment: PLEASE write this in $Tex$...otherwise it will be closed soon

Answer (score 1):

$$\int (x^2-6x)^\frac{3}{2} dx=\int \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt {(x-3)^2-9}}^3 \right)dx$$ so we will make $x-3=3\sec u$ transform. We will get $$\int \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt {9.(\frac {1}{\cos u})^2-9}}\right)^3\frac {3\sin u}{\cos^2 u}du\\=\int \left(\frac{1}{3\frac {\sin u}{\cos u}}\right)^3\frac {3\sin u}{\cos^2 u}du\\=\frac {1}{9} \int \frac {\cos u}{\sin^2 u}du\\=-\frac {1}{9\sin u}$$ We had made $x-3=3\sec u$ transform. So this will be equal to $$-\frac {1}{9\sqrt {1-\frac {1}{(x-3)^2}}}=\frac {3-x}{9\sqrt {x^2-6x+8}} $$

Answer (score 0):

Put $sin (\theta)=x $ thus $\cos (\theta)d\theta =dx $ then it can easily be integrated